# How to change object movement every 5 seconds using the timer in java?

Tags: java, timer

I have a object moving according to a certain algorithm and I want to make it move a different way every 5 seconds. How do i do that using the timer?

Comment: At least attempt to Google the information before asking on SO. this question shows little to no research effort.

Comment: In what? Swing, AWT, SWT, 3D, 2D, console??

Answer (score 2):

[See This](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

```
Timer time = new Timer();
time.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
    public void run(){
        //Do Stuff
    }
}, 0, 1000 * 5);
```